# provider not found for oracle OraOLEDB

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

I am trying to run a vba script in excel using Oracle db. When i try to establish a conn, it is showing some error like:

```
Connection Error
Import failed: 3706 - Provider cannot be found. it may not be installed properly.
```

I know there are many Q&A related to this, but i couldn't find any useful answers. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

please check with this code

```
Sub Oracle_Connection_VBA()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'Replace below with the corresponding values
    strcon = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=[Your Database];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[DB username];Password=[DbPassword]"
    con.Open (strcon)
    'do
    con.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: getting same error. Even though i have OraOLEDB*.dll files inside bin dir, it is throwing the error.

Comment: `OraOLEDB` is not `MSDAORA`. If you like to use the Oracle provider (which is the recommended one, because the Microsoft MSDAORA has been deprecated for years) you must use `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle`. OraOLEDB must be registered on the PC, simple file copy is not sufficient. Look for `REGSVR32.exe` if it is not registered.